# JavaFx keep window size after user resizes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml, scene

I currently use the following code to switch between scenes. I want to switch between windows and KEEP the window size (so when the users change the windows size manually by resizing the window, it will stay at the chosen size even after scene change).

`Scene scene = new Scene(pane); // new Scene(pane, userChosenWidth??, userChosenHeight??);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.sizeToScene();`

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: checkout this library it does everything you want to do to a stage : https://github.com/Oshan96/CustomStage

Answer (score 1):

Just call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on the current `Scene`. If you don't have a reference to the current scene, you can get one with `stage.getScene()`.

Answer (score 0):

I created this class:

```
public class AppSize {

    private static final String HEIGHT = "Height";
    private static final String WIDTH = "Width";
    private static final String Y = "Y";
    private static final String X = "X";

    private final static Preferences prefs =  Preferences.userNodeForPackage(AppSize.class);

    public static void setSize(Stage stage) {

    Optional.ofNullable(prefs.getDouble(X, -1)).filter(x->x>=0).ifPresent(stage::setX);
    Optional.ofNullable(prefs.getDouble(Y, -1)).filter(y->y>=0).ifPresent(stage::setY);
    Optional.ofNullable(prefs.getDouble(WIDTH, -1)).filter(width->width>=0).ifPresent(stage::setWidth);
    Optional.ofNullable(prefs.getDouble(HEIGHT, -1)).filter(height->height>=0).ifPresent(stage::setHeight);

    stage.setOnCloseRequest(
            e->{

                if(stage.isFullScreen()) {
                    return;
                }

                prefs.putDouble(X, stage.getX());
                prefs.putDouble(Y, stage.getY());
                prefs.putDouble(WIDTH, stage.getWidth());
                prefs.putDouble(HEIGHT, stage.getHeight());
            });
    }
}
```

its use:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
 
        var label = new Label("AppSize test.");
        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(label), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        AppSize.setSize(stage);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work!

Comment: I have changed my answer. Try to use the App from my example. This App works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Setting width and height in `Stage` worked for me.

```
double prevWidth = stage.getWidth();
double prevHeight = stage.getHeight();
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.setHeight(prevHeight);
stage.setWidth(prevWidth);
```